# How can I include an if statement in a paperclip post processor (ruby-on-rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm using paperclip for attached files in my database. The model that I'm currently working on requires both images and videos to be able to be used. I could just create two columns: one for images and one for videos but I'd rather not because it would make it a lot easier if it were just one. I'm using a post processor paperclip function that creates a thumbnail version of each image and a large version. The issue is that when I try to put a video in I get an error because the video obviously can't be formatted like an image can.

So, what I'm trying to do is put an if statement in the code so it only formats images, not videos.

Here's my code:

```
has_attached_file :attachment, :styles => lambda { |a| { :thumbnail => (a.content_type.include? "image" ? "174X174>" : ""), :large => (a.content_type.include? "image" ? '470' : "") } }
```

This is the error that I get when I try to use the model at all (when using the above code):

```
TypeError in Media#index

can't dup FalseClass
```

And here is the code that works but only with images:

```
has_attached_file :attachment, :url => "/system/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename", :styles => { :thumbnail => '174X174>', :large => '470' }
```

And this is the error I receive when using the above code:

```
Command :: identify -format %wx%h '/var/folders/it/itwSv-OMG0mneEX122X3I++++TY/-Tmp-/stream20140116-4704-1mlsrdy.mov[0]'
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: /var/folders/it/itwSv-OMG0mneEX122X3I++++TY/-Tmp-/stream20140116-4704-1mlsrdy.mov is not recognized by the 'identify' command.>
```

If it is a more complex issue than I think then I could just create a second column but I'd rather not, thanks.

Comment: First of all, I think, you are missing brackets around "image": a.content_type.include?("image") ? "174X174>" : ""